# How to add dynamic hostname for routing same request to different server using angular

Tags: angular

I have a usecase wherein i have to route request to different server to retrieve the user details.
For ex: I want to retrieve user details **API  :-/userdetails**  which exists on two server i.e. on localhost as well as on some other server(for ex:- 10.215.5.5).Now based on certain conditions i have to redirect this **userdetails** call to other server (other than localhost).How can i achieve this?

Comment: a browser can only make a call to the domain it is loaded from otherwise you will get into CORS issues.  Is this your dev requirement?  then you need to check starting ng serve with proxy - https://angular.io/guide/build#proxying-to-a-backend-server.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use the two URLs **(api end points)** and you need to put those URLs in the `environment.ts` and `environment.prod.ts` files. At the compile time the Angular Compiler will use the `environment.prod.ts` file as `environment.ts` file when you will create a production build.

**fileOne.ts**

```
import { environment } from "~/environment/environment.ts" 
console.log("Current API URL:", enviroment.apiUrl);
```

**environment.ts**

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  apiUrl: "http://localhost:4200"
}
```

**environment.prod.ts**

```
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  apiUrl: "https://10.215.5.5"
}
```

Inside the `angular.json` file all these file replacements will be going to happen

```
"fileReplacements": [
  {
    "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
    "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
  }
],
```

Comment: Both url required ,as it is in DA environment ,it is not like dev and production environment.based on certain checks I have to redirect request to other server for same request mapping (for ex. /userdetails )